# Is the generator of a uniformly continuous contraction semigroup contractive?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, semigroup-of-operators, contraction-operator

Let $E$ be a $\mathbb R$-Banach space and $A$ be the generator of a uniformly continuous contraction semigroup $(T(t))_{t\ge0}$ on $E$. Are we able to derive some bound on $\left\|A\right\|_{\mathfrak L(E)}$? Is $A$ even a contraction (i.e. has operator norm at most $1$)?

By assumption, $T(t)=e^{tA}$ and $\left\|T(t)\right\|_{\mathfrak L(E)}\le1$ for all $t\ge0$.

Comment: I'd expect to want some explicit control on "how uniformly continuous" $t \mapsto T(t)$ is at $0$ to get an explicit bound. This is because one explicit way to write $A$ in this case is to choose $h$ such $\|h^{-1} \int_0^h T_s ds - 1\| < 1$ (the integral is a Bochner integral and existence of such $h$ follows  from the FTC) and then check that $A = (T_h - 1) \bigg ( \int_0^h \|T_s - 1 \| ds \bigg)^{-1}$ where the inverse is given by the Von-Neumann series. Given such control, I could imagine being able to bound the terms involved in this expression.

Comment: @Surb Actually there is. The generator of a $C_0$-semigroup is bounded if and only if that semigroup is uniformly continuous.

Comment: @RhysSteele: good to know. Thank you :-)

Comment: @RhysSteele How do you obtain $A = (T_h - 1) \bigg ( \int_0^h \|T_s - 1 \| ds \bigg)^{-1}$? The only formula which I'm aware of is $$e^{-\lambda t}T(t)x-x=\begin{cases}\displaystyle(A-\lambda)\int_0^te^{-\lambda s}T(s)x\:{\rm d}s&\text{, if }x\in E\\\displaystyle\int_0^te^{-\lambda s}T(s)(A-\lambda)x\:{\rm d}s&\text{, if }x\in\mathcal D(A)\end{cases}$$ for all $\lambda\in\mathbb R$ and $t>0$ (clearly, in our case $\mathcal D(A)=E$).

Comment: @RhysSteele I've figured out that this will not work in the application I've got in mind and I need to take a different approach. I've asked for it here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3196006/47771. I'm sure you got some ideas. Would be great if you could take a look.

Comment: I'd made a slight typo, apologies. That should have read $A = (T_h - 1) \bigg (\int_0^h T_s - 1 ds \bigg)^{-1}$ (for some suitable $h$). See for example the proof of Theorem 3.27 [here](http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/~attal/Operator_Semigroups.pdf).

Comment: @RhysSteele I see. But as I said, unfortunately it doesn't help me. I had the hope that in this special situation the proof of Corollary 8.7 (in the other question) could be eased, but it seems like this is not the case.